# Using Gibbs Sampling on Deep Belief Network with PCA

Tags: deep-learning, deep-belief-networks

I'll make this question as clear as possible:

- If I were to PCA my data onto say 300 Principal components.
- Then train a deep belief network with 300 input features.
- Would I still be able to sample from the generative model (using
  [inverse transformations](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.PCA.inverse_transform) ?

Answer (score -1):

I wasn't thinking properly when I asked this:

Of course you can. Here is the algorithm:

```
gibbs_sample_pca = SampleGibbs()
Real_Sample = PCA.InverseTransform(gibbs_sample_pca)
```

Ta-da!!

Comment: Is this not the right way?